# C# Case statement or if statement depending on the filename a list is populated

Tags: c#, list, filenames

I am facing a problem and i really cant get out of it, i tried to search for some solutions but ran out of all ideas.. So i am selecting a number of files all names are numbers example 1.png , 2.png 3.png etc etc What i want is that when loading 2.png i get the filename for example 2 ( excluding the extension) check for a condition for example and if else condition and store the output in another list. Is it possible ? The code below shows how im loading a file and another thing which i am doing ( basically getting the image and passign the image to another method.

```
OpenFileDialog x = new OpenFileDialog();
        x.FileName = "";
        x.Multiselect = true;
        x.ShowDialog();
        x.Title = "Images";
        x.Filter = "Files|*.png";

        string[] result = x.FileNames;

        if (openFileDialog1.FileNames.ToString() != "")
        {
            foreach (string y in result)
            {

                img = new Bitmap(y);
                ContoBin(img);     
            }                


        }
```

Comment: Your question *really* isn't clear to me - what do you mean by "check for a condition for example and if else condition and store the output in another list"? What *exactly* are you having problems with?

Comment: So you want to check a condition on a list of filenames? Can you share the condition? What would be your expected input and output?

Comment: Yep you are right i tried to make it as clear as possible but apparently didnt manage.. sorry about that.. My problem is that i am loading a number of files named 2.png 3.png 4.png i want to get the filenames ( 2,3and 4) if the filename is 2 then i will assign a binary value of 0110 , if its 3 i will assign a binary value of 0111 etc etc

Comment: @Etienne so... you want to add 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get your filename without your extension?

```
foreach (string y in result)
{
    if((Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(y) == "2")
    {
         // do stuff with 2.png
    }  

    ...
```

make sure you have

```
using System.IO;
```

at the top of your code file

Comment: i am not using a path i am just using an OpenFileDialog when writing that part i am getting that Path doesnt exist in this context which he's right..

Comment: @Etienne  `Path` is just a utility class in the `System.IO` namespace,  all it does is string manipulation.   so if you have the filename: `"2.png"`, then `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("2.png")` will return "2"

Comment: yep but for some reason I've already added that System.IO before i just deleted it and re-wrote and it worked o_O ! Just a small question is it possible to work this way however instead of 2 i compare the filename to a range of numbers... if the filename is between 0 and 40 then do some things ?

Comment: @Etienne most primitive types have a `Parse` method that you can use to parse strings.  So if you type `int i = int.Parse("2")` you should get the interger `2` back in `i`